# Converegence of modulus in nocommutative $L_p$-spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $1\leq p<\infty.$ Let $\mathcal M$ be a von Neumann algebra equipped with a normal semifinite faithful trace $\tau.$ Let $L_p(\mathcal M,\tau)$ be the associated noncommutative $L_p$-space. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $L_p(\mathcal M,\tau)$ such that $\|x_n-x\|_p\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for some $x\in L_p(\mathcal M,\tau).$ Is it true that $\||x_n|-|x|\|_p\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems false for $p=1$, see the following:

> *Caspers, M.; Potapov, D.; Sukochev, F.; Zanin, D.*, [**Weak type
>   estimates for the absolute value
>   mapping**](http://dx.doi.org/10.7900/jot.2013dec20.2021), J. Oper.
>   Theory 73, No. 2, 361-384 (2015).
>   [ZBL1389.47063](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1389.47063).

Comment: The results in that paper would solve your question for the other $p$

Comment: The modulus map is continuous for $p=1$ as well (although it's not Lipschitz), by Borchers and also by Kosaki [JFA 59 (1984), 123-131].